# Custom label for a SELECT in Spring Roo

Tags: select, spring-roo

I am starting with Spring Roo. In my project, I have to entities with a one-to-many relation. In my controller, when I edit one entity, I get an HTML SELECT to choose one of the other entity. I'd like to have a custom label in this SELECT.

I tried to register a Converter in my ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean :

```
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends
  FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

  @Override
  protected void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    super.installFormatters(registry);
    // Register application converters and formatters
    registry.addConverter(getApplicationConverter());
  }

  public Converter<Application, String> getApplicationConverter() {
    return new Converter<Application, String>() {
      @Override
      public String convert(Application source) {
        return "toto" + source.getName();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This doesnt seem to work, the SELECT is still filled with what looks like the result of Application.toString().

What am I missing ?

Comment: You have posted the same question twice. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664258/using-converters-in-a-list-with-spring-roo/6742509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution. I still dont know if it is the right one ...

```
public class ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean extends
  FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {

  static class ApplicationConverter implements Converter<Application, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(Application source) {
      return "toto" + source.getName();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void installFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    super.installFormatters(registry);
    // Register application converters and formatters
    registry.addConverter(new ApplicationConverter());
  }
}
```

This seems to work for the labels in a SELECT. Is it the recommended way ?