# Using converters in a list with Spring Roo

Tags: model-view-controller, list, spring-roo

Now that I found [how to use converters in an HTML SELECT in Spring Roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663725/custom-label-for-a-select-in-spring-roo), I am trying to do the same in a list.

I managed to register a Converter in my ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean, but now I need to use it as well when displaying a list of my envities. I have the following entity :

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Environment {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Application application;
}
```

When displaying it as a list in the generated MVC, it looks like the application is displayed as a toString() and not using the registered converter.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to push-in refactor the Roo generated converter method to the application conversion factory bean.

Sometimes, by default `toString()` method is used for the conversion.

Alternatively, you can try pushing in and overriding the `toString()` method within the entity itself. You will have to remove the `@RooToString` annotation while doing this.

Cheers!!!